# Can someone provide an example about Realm data store repository with Xamarin.Forms and UI databinding?

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, xamarin.forms, realm, repository-pattern

I am currently developing an app with Xamarin.Forms and I choose Realm as my data provider. I would like to use the repository pattern in order to get more flexibility on changing my data provider and to improve my code quality/lisibility. But the Realm dotnet implementation is still young and I didn't find lots of samples on google about that. Is there someone who would have the kindess to give me some sources as samples please? :)

Thanks,
Sebastien

Comment: https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest/

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to bind?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out PRO-PD, https://github.com/rsatter/PRO-PD. It uses IOC and has Realm as a data service.